# How to refactor repetitive attributes in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

Suppose I have a form and many fields in it. I want to subscribe to `change` for each form field. I will have to add `@change="doSome"` for every field. If I have many fields it gets somewhat repetitive. How do I refactor it?

Comment: I suppose if they are inside a form tag, you can just add `@change` on that. I believe this will listen for changes in all children

Comment: if you convert things into reusable components then it won't be repetitive

Comment: @SølveTornøe my form tag is a component provided by some vendor. It does not introduce a change event

Comment: @JacobGoh I have made several attempts to do so. You still have to inject mny things inside such a component like a model and a field name

Comment: aha, can you try adding @change.native="doSome"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen for the change event on the form tag itself instead of listening on the individual inputs.

`<form @change="doSomething">` will run the function `doSomething()` when something inside the form has changed eg: if you type in an input **and release focus**

In the doSomething function, you want to find out what element changed. We get this info from the event parameter provided from the input event:

```
methods: {
  doSomething(event) {
    this.lastEvent = event.target.value;
  }
}
```

You can see this in effect on this [Codepen example](https://codepen.io/BlitZZ96/pen/YLbjMX)

If the form element is a child of an element inside a component like so:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <form></form>
  </div>
</template>
```

the `@change`event-listener will not work as there is nothing that changes on the root element (div) on the component.

In this case, we need to add the **.native** modifier, like so: `@change.native="doSomething"`.

Comment: Sweet, happy to help! 